# (Python)Why the sum of list of list and [] is a list?

Tags: sum

Why the result of code below is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]?

```
In[10]:=sum([[1,2,3], [4,5]],[])
Out[10]:=[1,2,3,4,5]  # why the result is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]?
```

The purpose is to get item of all the list in the list [[1,2,3], [4,5]].
(I don't know why "[]" in the second argument of sum.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

```py
sum([1, 2, 3], 0)
```

means `0 + 1 + 2 + 3` ,

then

```py
sum([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], [])
```

means: `[] + [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5]`